# Density vs ocean planet?

Tags: planetary-science, planet

According to [Nasa.gov](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/news/1710/discovery-alert-intriguing-new-super-earth-could-get-a-closer-lo):

> Details: Ocean planets are long imagined but difficult to confirm, and TOI-1452 b is no different. About 70% larger than Earth, and roughly five times as massive, its density could be consistent with having a very deep ocean. But more follow-up will be needed. The planet also might be a huge rock, with little or no atmosphere. It could even be a rocky planet with an atmosphere of hydrogen and helium.

The new super-earth is said to have a density that is "consistent with having a very deep ocean". What does this mean and how is this calculated? The article unfortunately provides no more details as more information is needed to be gathered from the planet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More details can be found in [**"TOI-1452 b: SPIRou and TESS Reveal a Super-Earth in a Temperate Orbit Transiting
an M4 Dwarf"**](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/ac7cea/pdf).

The water planet possibility discussions starts on page 14.

What they are essentially saying is that you *could* have a water planet with this mass and radius. That is, the then required composition of the interior would be within what models say are normal.

They mention two other possibilities though:

> (2) a bare rock
> with an iron content less than that of Earth
> (3) a terrestrial
> planet with a thin, low molecular weight atmosphere (e.g.,
> H–He)

That's a big range of possibilities, which shouldn't be surprising since the only things we know are the mass, radius and orbital radius of the planet.

Rephrased: "This *could* be a water planet. There's nothing wrong with it"

Another thing that doesn't disagree with this being a water planet is the surface temperature. By making a guess at the albedo of the planet, they can use the orbital radius to estimate an equilibrium temperature of 298 ±
6 K. Liquid water could exist at those temperatures.

But the bottom line is that "consistent with" is a much less exciting thing than one may initially get the impression of when that's the only part that makes it into a popular science article.

Comment: Did you find anything about the very deep ocean?

Comment: "(1) an ocean planet" is the language used.